# Cannot build react-native project for web that uses @sentry/react-native and react-native-web

Tags: react-native, webpack, babeljs, sentry, react-native-web

The existing configuration for compilation seems to have issues compiling some syntax used in sentry source code. The screenshot [image] shows two places where the exception occurs.

Here is the configuration used

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')

const appDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../')

// This is needed for webpack to compile JavaScript.
// Many OSS React Native packages are not compiled to ES5 before being
// published. If you depend on uncompiled packages they may cause webpack build
// errors. To fix this webpack can be configured to compile to the necessary
// `node_module`.
const babelLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.js$/,
  // Add every directory that needs to be compiled by Babel during the build.
  include: [
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'index.web.js'),
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'src'),
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'prebundled'),
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'node_modules/react-native')
  ],
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      // The 'metro-react-native-babel-preset' preset is recommended to match React Native's packager
      presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
      // Re-write paths to import only the modules needed by the app
      plugins: [
        'react-native-web',
        [
          'module-resolver',
          {
            alias: {
              '^react-native$': 'react-native-web'
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}

// This is needed for webpack to import static images in JavaScript files.
const imageLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]',
      esModule: false
    }
  }
}

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    // load any web API polyfills
    // path.resolve(appDirectory, 'polyfills-web.js'),
    // your web-specific entry file
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'index.web.js')
  ],

  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    publicPath: '/',
    path: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'dist')
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      babelLoaderConfiguration,
      imageLoaderConfiguration,
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        // exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          configFile: 'tsconfig.web.json',
          transpileOnly: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
      resourceRegExp: /react-native-screens/
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, './index.html')
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          context: __dirname,
          from: './images/**/*',
          to: '[path][name][ext]',
          force: true
        },
        { from: path.join(__dirname, './main.css'), to: './main.css' },
        {
          from: path.join(__dirname, './.well-known/apple-app-site-association'),
          to: './.well-known/'
        }
      ]
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
      'react-native-maps$': 'react-native-web-maps'
    },
    extensions: ['.web.tsx', '.web.ts', '.tsx', '.ts', '.web.js', '.js', '.json']
  }
}
```

I tried implementing something that looks like showing in this documentation but it did not help.
[https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/sourcemaps/uploading/webpack/](https://webpack%20for%20react)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@sentry/react-native` to compile.
Update you webpack config like this:

```
...
const compileNodeModules = [
'@sentry/react-native'
]
const babelLoaderConfiguration = {
...
...compileNodeModules
}
```